# The problem of concentration (Clarification of statement in Evans: Weak Convergence Methods for Nonlinear PDE)

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, geometric-measure-theory

I am working through Evan's book on Weak Convergence Methods for Nonlinear PDE. He assumes that $U$ is an open bounded smooth subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $1<q<n$. In ($\S$D) concerning Measures of Concentration he assumes that $f_k$ is a sequence of functions in $L^q(U)$ that converge weakly to $f$ but not strongly to $f$. He has the following statement under this section :

> Secondly, observe that even if we somehow know additionally
>   $f_k \rightarrow f\ a.e.$ in U;
>   so that wild oscillations are excluded, we still cannot legitimately deduce strong convergence
>   in $L^q(U)$. The obstruction is that the mass of $\vert f_k-f\vert^q$ may somehow coalesce onto
>   a set of zero Lebesgue measure. This is the problem of concentration.

I am trying to understand what he means by

> $\dots$ the mass of $\vert f_k-f\vert^q$ may somehow coalesce onto
>   a set of zero Lebesgue measure $\dots$

Does he mean that as $k\rightarrow\infty$ that (somehow):
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}^n(\{x\in U\vert\ \vert f_k(x)-f(x)\vert ^q\neq 0\})\rightarrow 0,
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}^n$ is the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that he means something like
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}^n(\{x\in U\vert\ \vert f_k(x)-f(x)\vert ^q > \epsilon\})\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
for all $\epsilon > 0$.

An example of such behaviour is the sequence of functions in $L^2(0,1)$
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt n & 0 < x < 1/n, \\
0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$ and $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, but $\|f_n\|_{L^2} = 1$.

Comment: Nice example! That seems to make sense because if we let $E_k=\{x\in U\vert\ \vert f_k-f\vert^q>\varepsilon\}$ where $f_k\rightharpoonup f$ in $L^q(U)$ and $f_k\rightarrow f$ a.e. in $U$, then:\begin{equation}\int_{U}\vert f_k-f\vert^q\text{ d}\mathcal{L}^n>\int_{E_k}\varepsilon\text{ d}\mathcal{L}^n=\varepsilon\mathcal{L}^n(E_k)\quad\forall\ \varepsilon>0\end{equation}
and assuming that the $E_k$'s are not all null sets This in turn would mean
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{U}\vert f_k-f\vert^q\text{ d}\mathcal{L}^n>0
\end{equation}
whence the problem of concentration, right?

Comment: Yes, such an accumulation of "mass" would prevent convergence.